# Reduce the refresh time with angular live-debug

Tags: angular, debugging

I'm using `angular 4` installed with `CLI`.
`Live debuging` is working and refreshes my page on chrome `automatically, when my code changes.`

I didn't find after multiple researchs how to reduce the time for an `instant refresh` (At this moment, I have to wait few seconds before the refreshing of my page on chrome).

Comment: Some people have to wait few minutes...

Comment: Buy a faster computer.... :)

Comment: A few seconds is ok. Get an SSD?

Comment: Hahaha stop trolling me, I thought it was configurable!

Comment: mine refreshes after 30+ seconds, you should be thankful :D :D

Comment: haha, damn it D:

Comment: You can reduce compile time by moving code to npm modules that are already compiled and/or disable source maps. Take a look at the AnguarClass  starter kit: https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter